# Spring bean always returns same value even when condition is false

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa to populate audit data for my entities.

We have a quartz job that runs nightly, which will not be authenticated, and in such cases we want the "createdBy" value to be "system". In other cases, we want it to be populated with currently logged in user.

When I create a Purcahse order via UI, the "createdBy" field is always populated with "system" instead of the user ID that's logged in currently.

I tried making the AuditorAware bean lazy and changed the scope to prototype and they both didn't work. 
I put a breakpoint in the code and I can see the SecurityContext and Authentication objects are not null yet it still returns "system"

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Purchase{
    String purchaseNbr;
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;
}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class Auditconfig{
    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditAware(){
        if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()==null || SecurityContextHolder.getContext.getAuthentication() == null ) {
             //during spring context initialization, i can see this branch gets hit, if i put a breakpoint here
             return () -> Optional.of("system");
        }else {
             //this branch never gets hit even when "if" condition is false during runtime
             return () -> Optional.of(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
         }

    }
}
```

Expected "createdBy" to be current user but was always "system"

Comment: The code you posted can't possibly compile. You're returning a String from a method which is supposed to return an AuditorAware<String>.

Comment: @JBNizet We're not allowed to copy paste our code outside. So had to type it. It's a typo. I have made the change above.

Comment: You're returning an object that always returns `Optional.of("system")`, or always returns `Optional.of(Security...)`, depending on the value of the security context when the bean is created , at startup. At startup, it's always null? So you return an object that always returns Optional.of("system"). You need to put the if statement ** after** the arrow: `return () -> { if (...) { return ...; } else { return ... }`/ That way, every time the AuditorAware is called, you check, at that time, the value of the authentication.

Comment: @JBNizet This worked ask you suggested. If you can post your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `auditAware()` is only executed once, at startup. At this time, there's no current user. So you're always returning

```
() -> Optional.of("system")
```

And this AuditorAware instance, whenever it's called later, will thus always return

```
Optional.of("system")
```

What you want is an AuditAware that, whenever it's called later, tests who the current user is, and determines what it should return. So it should be

```
@Bean
public AuditorAware<String> auditAware(){
    return () -> {
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext() == null || SecurityContextHolder.getContext.getAuthentication() == null) {
            return Optional.of("system");
        } else {
            return Optional.of(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
        }
    }
}
```